# Does Azure B2C have an end user portal "app endpoint" dashboard?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, windows-live-id, microsoft-identity-platform

Is there any Azure B2C end-user queryable endpoint that will allow that owner to identify which tenants they have authenticated to?

A dashboard for B2C users that is an aggregate of all tenants they have federated with?  Is there some extension of the /common endpoint I could make an OAuth query to? (ideally including AAD B2B guest accounts)

- https://account.live.com/Activity
- https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications
- myapps.microsoft.com

---

4/24/20 Edit:

I found this in the portal that implies a portal is available.

[image]
I'm looking for the API in which to programmatically add applications to it before a migration.

I need to have the applications already 'signed in' or linked to applications I own in the B2C directory (OIDC/SAML2 apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is the equivalent of asking, "Can i find out if i registered at StackOverflow and Facebook with this/my email?". You cannot do this, AAD B2C is isolated tenancies representing a single organisations' identities. There is no equivalent of /common endpoint for AAD B2C. In AAD and AAD B2B accounts, there is a mapping created from the original account to identify which tenants they are in. This is to maintain a single identity across the Microsoft ecosystem. 
In AAD B2C, this doesn't exist, goes back to my first sentence for 'why', they are separate applications, and inherently have no relationship, nor do the identities.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm looking for a list of which accounts on SO to follow re B2C, and yours is first on the list. If there are others, and they want to be known, perhaps a blog @ mention of those accounts might be beneficial for nerds like me who are trying to learn (everything) about the product. TY

Comment: Hello Jas! I just observed that the setting in B2C was for a portal actually refers to Enterprise account; not B2C accounts. Thank you again, Jas

Comment: Portal is referring to the My Apps portal, which doesn't apply to B2C applications. It applies to Azure AD applications.